# Obtain Image path for CGImageSourceRef

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, exif

Hey guys, i'm currently trying to get the EXIF data from an image selected by the user via the `UIIMagePickerController`. I can't seem to get my head around how I would obtain a path I can use for the `CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)someURL,nil)`.

When I try to use the `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` the console spits out a rather nice error : `<ERROR> CGImageSourceCreateWithURLCFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource failed with error code -11.`. I'm stumped, I'm starting to think I'm coming from a whole wrong angle, since the `CGImageSourceRef` type is generally used to create an image, while I already have a `UIImage`. Anyone that can shed some light on this matter, please feel free to do so.

`- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)pickerdidFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {`

```
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]){
    image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSLog(@"%@",[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]);
    //Outputs: assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000006&ext=JPG
    CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL], nil);

    //The plan is to somehow get a CGImageSourceRef object from the 
    //UIImage provided by the [info UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage], i just don't know how to get this object,
    // for it requires the URL to the image, wich i don't seem to have.
    }

}
```

-Edit-
Will use the workaround offered by more tension. Thanks for reading.

Comment: you should +1 bump @more_tension if that helped you.

Comment: I bumped the actual answer, it's a bit further down :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error code -11 means the URL scheme is unrecognized, which is to say the CFURL doesn't know what to do with URLs beginning with assets-library://.

Why do you think you need a CGImageSourceRef in this case?

Comment: Since i'm planning to read the EXIF data from the image using the ImageIO framework. The method for this (`CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex`) requires a CGImageSourceRef object passed as argument. I reckon i'd also need to use a `CGImageSourceRef` that's actually a reference to the image, returned by `UIImagePickerController`. I just have no idea how I would go about to retrieve the right URL. I figured the Asset URL isn't what i was looking for, since i tried the `ALAsset` framework, wich ended up being insufficient.

Comment: The workaround is probably to save the original image data locally, and then use `CGImageSourceCreateWithURL` to get the `CGImageSource`.

Comment: Hmm, that might be a possibility, i'll have to make sure all EXIF data is retained through that process, but thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

**ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [yourAsset defaultRepresentation];

 NSDictionary *metadataDict = [[representation metadata]retain];**

Comment: [representation metadata] does not return all the EXIF information like Camera make or aperture, etc..